# How to iterate through elements in DOMNodeList?

Tags: php, loops, dom

I am having a problem iterating through elements in a DOMNodeList. I am trying to put a whole paragraph into a string. I can get each sentence separately using this:

```
$node = $paragraph->item(0);  //first line of the paragraph
$node = $paragraph->item(1);  //second line of the paragraph
```

But I cannot seem to loop through all of the sentences and put them into the one string. I have tried this but it didn't work:

```
for($i=0; $i<3; $i++)
{
    $node = $paragraph->item($i); 
}
```

Any ideas how I could do this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

DOMNodeList implements Traversable, just use foreach()

```
foreach($nodeList as $node) {
  //...
}
```

Of course a for is possible, too.

```
$length = $nodeList->length;
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
  $node = $nodeList->item($i);
  //...
}
```

To get all the text content inside a node, the $nodeValue or $textContent properties can be used:

```
$text = '';
foreach($nodeList as $node) {
  $text .= $node->textContent;
}
```

But this is for a node list. You said that this is the text content of a paragraph. If you have the paragraph as an DOMElement object, it has $nodeValue and $textContent properties as well.

```
$text = $paragraphNode->textContent;
```

And if you fetched the nodes via Xpath, DOMXpath::evaluate() can return the text content as a string.

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$text = $xpath->evaluate('string(//p[1])');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's now iterating through the list but it is only keeping the last sentence in the paragraph. Is there a way to concatenate the list items together in the for loop, or use a '+=" type of thing?

Comment: I added some infos about the second part of the question. :-)

Comment: Thanks! Very well explained really appreciate it. Solved my problem exactly.

Answer (score 3):

I found iterating over even a moderately a large DOMNodeList to be ***very slow*** using `foreach()`.  A much faster method is to use the [DOMNode `$nextSibling`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.nextsibling) property in `do-while` loop like this:

```
$el = $paragraph->firstChild;
do {
    // do stuff
} while ($el = $el->nextSibling);
```

This is also mentioned in a comment on php.net [here](http://php.net/manual/en/domnodelist.item.php#101718).